# How to show that a function from a metric space to the real numbers is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, and $p$ a point of $X$. Define a function $ f: X \rightarrow \mathbb R, f(x) = d(x,p)$. Prove that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Triangle inequality...

Comment: Have you considered writing down the definition of continuity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We'll prove the following more general lemma:

**Lemma:** Let $A$ be a non empty subset of a metric space $(X,d)$ then the function $f: X \to \mathbb R$ given by $f(x)=d(x,A)$ is uniformly continuous.

Because $$| f(x) - f(y) | = | d(x,A) - d(y,A) | \leq d(x,y)$$.

This means that $f$ is uniformly continuous (use $\delta = \epsilon$ in any point).Recall that every uniformly continuous function  is continuous so $f$ is also continuous.Now you can set $A$ to be singelton set containing p.